Multi-Arch Docker Images from .Net 8 Publish Command
I can't find any documentation about how to create a multi-arch docker container with the .NET 8 dotnet publish command. I want to be able to do something like the following.
dotnet publish ./Wowshop.API/Wowshop.API.csproj /t:PublishContainer -r linux-x64;linux-arm64

I am wanted to run this in GitHub actions, if there is a multi-step process to do that.
